# Portuguese (Austria resident) to register relationship with a Philippine

Tags: visa, family, schengen, austria, portugal

Me and my boyfriend want to live together and settle down. I'm from the Philippines and currently working in Dubai and my boyfriend is Portuguese and working in Austria. The plan is for me to move to Austria.

I've a degree and several years of working experience in my field of studies.

My profession is listed in the [Shortage Occupations list](http://www.migration.gv.at/en/types-of-immigration/permanent-immigration/skilled-workers-in-shortage-occupations/#c2938) but it requires me to speak German which I don't and it will take me some time. I can't get a job seeker visa by just a few points (less than 10points) so I am only left with a tourist visa which is not enough for our plans.

Our plan is to register our relationship (this is marrying, correct?) and then request family reunion visa and I move to Austria. Because my boyfriend is not Austrian, requesting the family reunion visa does not requires me to speak German (A1 level at least), am I right?

To marry in the Philippines my boyfriend's documents have to be attested by his country embassy in the Philippines [[source](http://www.filipiknow.net/how-to-get-married-in-the-philippines/amp/), [source]](https://www.bohol.ph/article121.html) but Portugal's embassy responsible for the Philippines is in Indonesia. This would force him to go to Indonesia to take care of all the paper work and then go to the Philippines.

It is possible for him to deal with all relationship registration's paper work with the embassy in Austria or his home country before traveling to the Philippines for the formal process?

Which process is easier to do?

1. Register our relationship in Austria.
2. Register our relationship in Portugal.
3. Register our relationship in the Philippines.
4. Register our relationship in Abu Dhabi at the Portuguese/Philippine embassy
5. Other, which one?

Another alternative I was told about is for my boyfriend to sponsor me to go to Austria, how does this exactly works and is it possible for our case? He has accommodation and a job.

Are we forgetting another alternative that we should take in consideration?

Comment: It might be simplest to do it in Austria since that's where you plan to live.  It looks like you can do it if you go on a tourist visa.  See https://www.help.gv.at/Portal.Node/hlpd/public/content/142/Seite.1420000.html.  But how long have you been together?  You may also be able to apply for freedom of movement as a "partner in a durable relationship."

Comment: @phoog I don't see any mention that someone can marry in Austria on a tourist visa from the link you provided, could you tell where you got that information? We have been together for close to 6 months, is this considered a durable relationship?

Comment: I don't see any mention of immigration status at all; that suggests that it does not matter.  Six months probably does not constitute a durable relationship, especially if you have never lived together.